How to interpret blendshape data in maya
I'm trying to export deltas from all blendshapes (and inbetweens) from maya, and find a way to use that data in unity.
I found a way to get the deltas from this site https://www.tech-artists.org/t/maya-blendshape-delta/12641.
pt = cmds.getAttr('blendShape1.inputTarget[0].inputTargetGroup[0].inputTargetItem[6000].inputPointsTarget')
ct = cmds.getAttr('blendShape1.inputTarget[0].inputTargetGroup[0].inputTargetItem[6000].inputComponentsTarget')

pt count: 1054 data: [dt.Point([0.21583744883537292, -0.02462431788444519, 0.5327363014221191]),...
ct count: 242 data: ['vtx[0:45]', 'vtx[56:85]', 'vtx[88]', 'vtx[91:96]',...

pt holds all the deltas, and the ct holds the vertex indices that get each delta. I'm just not sure how to understand this data. The pt array is longer than ct, so i can't just map them 1 to 1.
Does anyone know how to interpret the two arrays?
i didn't try anything, since i don't understand the data returned.
